# Getting "no transaction is in progress" in Spring Junit test

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, JUnit 4.8.1, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.  I'm trying to run this JUnit test …

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
public class UserDaoImplTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{
    …
    @Test
    public final void testSave()
    {
        final User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(testProps.getProperty("test.user.first.name"));
        user.setLastName(testProps.getProperty("test.user.last.name"));
        user.setMiddleName(testProps.getProperty("test.user.middle.name"));
        user.setPassword(testProps.getProperty("test.user.password"));
        final Role role = rolesDao.findRoleByName(testProps.getProperty("test.role.teacher.name"));
        user.setRole(role);
        user.setUrl(testProps.getProperty("test.user.url"));
        user.setUserName(testProps.getProperty("test.user.username"));
        final User savedUser = userDao.save(user);
        Assert.assertNotNull(savedUser.getId());
        final User foundUser = userDao.findById(savedUser.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(savedUser, foundUser);
    }   // testSave
```

and on the "userDao.save" line, I'm getting the fullowing exception.  I thought "AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests" guarantees each test to be transactional?  What can I do to solve this?

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:971)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at $Proxy30.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.repo.UserDaoImpl.save(UserDaoImpl.java:118)
    at org.mainco.subco.user.test.repo.UserDaoImplTest.testSave(UserDaoImplTest.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here are the contents of the test-context.xml file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco" />

    <!-- Define hashing properties -->
    <bean id="localPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:encryption.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Define test properties -->
    <util:properties id="applicationProperties" location="classpath:test.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/ebook-test" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/test-persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="usersTestingDatabase" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sharedEntityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="bcProvider" class="${hash.provider.class}" />

    <bean id="jasyptStringDigester" class="org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester">
        <property name="algorithm">
            <value>${digest.algorithm}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="provider">
            <ref bean="bcProvider" />
        </property>
        <property name="saltGenerator">
            <ref bean="saltGenerator" />
        </property>
        <property name="saltSizeBytes" value="${salt.bytes.length}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="saltGenerator" class="${salt.generator.class}" />

    <!-- This Spring Security-friendly PasswordEncoder implementation will -->
    <!-- wrap the StringDigester instance so that it can be used from -->
    <!-- the security framework. -->
    <bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.jasypt.springsecurity3.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder">
        <property name="stringDigester">
            <ref bean="jasyptStringDigester" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="embedded" type="H2" />
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

Comment: have you defined a transactionmanager in test-context.xml

Comment: Also since your using annotations in most of your test code you could just add @Transactional to you test.  The default is to rollback.

Comment: @NimChimpsky - I included the contents of my test-context.xml file.  Note that I do define a TransactionManager, but perhaps it is related to taht somehow.

Comment: Does your DAO uses the entity manager or is it some think different (SpringData or standart jdbc)?

Comment: The DAO autowires in a "javax.persistence.EntityManager" object, defined in the test context by the bean with id "sharedEntityManager".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all that, the problem was that the userDao and rolesDao objects were using different entity managers, one being autowired from teh context, and the other being instantiated in the test.

Answer (score 1):

Something with your configuration seams to be wrong: you have two datasources!
One explicite defined:

```
 <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/ebook-test" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

and one implicite defined:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="embedded" type="H2" />
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-test-data.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

When I do tests like you did, my setup looks like this (and it works):

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" >
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:ddlAdditional_h2.sql" />       
</jdbc:embedded-database>   

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testH2DbPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <!-- this is important to connect JPA and JdbcTemplate transaction control -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

---

*BTW: Add `@Transactional` to individual test methods or to your test class (this is like adding it to all test methods). Then you do not need to extend `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` anymore.*

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImplTest {

   @Test  
   public test() {...}
}
```

Then the test methods will run in a transaction that will be rollbacked at the end.

Comment: I removed the "extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests" and added the @Transactional annotation but still got the same error upon rerunning the test.

Comment: I have added some comment about the configuration, I hope this helps you. (Btw: my setup uses an inmmemory db for the test)

Comment: Hi, I also use an inmemory db, so your setup helps me.  But I have a question -- I insert test data using the SQL script, but I auto-create the table structure using the "<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>" property defined in my test-persistence.xml file.  How do you generate your inmemory table structures?

Comment: @Dave: I use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`  so it is in the end the same way you do.